# ¿Para qué sirve y cómo funciona la palabra clave "with" en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

He encontrado bloques de código de este tipo:

```
with a as b:
    c = b.algo()
```

Parecería alguna dinámica similar a `namespaces`, pero el siguiente código

```
a = 1
with a as b:
    print a, b
```

regresa el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Entonces, ¿para qué sirve la palabra clave `with`, y cómo funciona? ¿Cuál es el rol de `__exit__`?

Comment: Hola Teental. Para tu información, quité las etiquetas que especificaban las versiones de Python ya que pusistes mas de uno.  Si la pregunta aplica a una versión específica, entonces puedes agregar la etiqueta adecuada para esa versión. Pero si tu pregunta es general, por favor no agregues etiquetas para todas las versiones.

Comment: @sstan `with` no se encuentra disponible en todas las versiones de Python, pero si en las que especifiqué. Es por ello que las etiquetas son necesarias. Si acaso lo que queremos es remover la general y dejar las específicas, edición que acabo de realizar.

Comment: Mejor no quitar la etiqueta Python porque, a no ser que planees añadir etiquetas para todas las versiones presentes  y futuras que usen `with`, va a hacer más fácil de encontrar la pregunta (es Python en general, y esas versiones en particular)

Comment: Por cierto, muy interesante la pregunta :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

La claúsula `with` no tiene en python la función de delimitar el *espacio de nombres* (*"namespaces"*) como se hace en otros lenguajes como VB. Es más para determinar la configuración local que tendrá un bloque de código, lo que se conoce como **"contexto"**.

Un *"contexto"* básicamente se establece con una configuración inicial y una finalización para recuperar los valores anteriores. Un ejemplo sería la apertura de un fichero:

```
with open("fichero.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Empezamos el bloque abriendo el fichero y, al acabar, se cerrará el fichero automáticamente, aunque no se haya indicado explícitamente.

Para controlar un contexto, se usan los **"gestores de contexto"** (*"context manager"*) que son objetos que tienen definidos los métodos `__enter__` y `__exit__`. El primero para inicializar el contexto, el segundo para finalizarlo.

Los objetos `files` en python implementan el interface de *gestor de contexto*, por lo que su uso en contextos asegurarán que los ficheros se van a cerrar correctamente.

Hay muchos más objetos en la librería estándar que implementan el interface de gestor de contextos. Uno de los más significativos es el tipo [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), donde a través de un contexto puedes especificar la precisión decimal de las operaciones que se realizarán dentro del bloque:

```
from decimal import localcontext

with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 42   # Precisión de 42 cifras significativas
    s = calculate_something() # cálculo de alta precisión

s = +s  # regreso a la precisión por defecto del tipo decimal
```

Hay también librerías, como [fabric](http://fabfile.org/), que usan los contextos para establecer la configuración de las conexiones de los servidores sobre los que ejecutar un script.

En tu caso, el error que te da es que la variable `a` no tiene definidos los métodos de *gestor de contextos*.

Para información más detallada, mírate el [PEP-343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: Interesante soy nuevo en el mundo de Python, pero cuando hablas de "implementan el interfaz" es una metáfora? Tenía entendido que en Python no hay interfaces. O como se haría este tipo de implementación en Python. Un saludo.

Comment: Python es un lenguaje dinámico, por lo que no podemos establecer reglas estrictas en las validaciones de tipos de datos. Pero sí que emplea "tipos estructurales", más conocidos como "duck types". También tiene ["clases abstractas"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) que pueden validar sus interfaces gracias al uso de metaclases. Pero lo habitual es asumir que los objetos que recibes tienen las propiedades esperadas antes que probar que es falso ([principio "EFAP"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)).

Comment: Veo que me queda bastante que aprender de Python. ¿Algún consejo?

Comment: Lo principal es que te divierta aprender. Si tienes interés en este tema, el libro ["Dive into python"](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) lo explica bastante bien (hace un listado de interfaces en el apéndice ["Special Method Name"](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html)). Para cualquier duda, por aquí estaremos.

Comment: es posible poner mas de un with en un programa? y si es posible como seria?

Comment: Es como si anidaras un `with` dentro de otro. Se explica muy bien en la [documentación del with](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: Por si alguien está pensando escribir su propio context manager, recomiendo que, en vez de implementar manualmente `__enter__` y `__exit__`, utilice el decorador [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).