# Hash de documentos con hashlib, TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación donde pueda indicar un fichero y sus hashes (SHA1, SHA256, md5).

El problema es que a la hora de sacar el hash me reporta el siguiente error, haciendo referencia a una API faltante:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Python/venv/Herramientas/Hashes.py", line 18, in 
>       objeto_hash = hashlib.sha1(objeto_fichero) TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

El código es el siguiente:

```
import hashlib
ruta = 'C:\Python\pep8es.pdf'
objeto_fichero = open(ruta,mode = 'rb')
#cadena_input = input('Introduce la cadena para sacar su hash: ')
#sha1
objeto_hash = hashlib.sha1(objeto_fichero)
hex_dig = objeto_hash.hexdigest()
print('sha1-> ',hex_dig)
#sha256
objeto_hash = hashlib.sha256(objeto_fichero)
hex_dig = objeto_hash.hexdigest()
print('sha224->',hex_dig)
#md5
objeto_hash = hashlib.md5(b'Hola gente')
hex_dig = objeto_hash.hexdigest()
print('md5->',hex_dig)
```

¿Alguien me puede indicar donde falla o por donde puedo tirar para solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto los constructores de los algoritmos como el método `update` requieren tal como dice el error  objetos `bytes-like` que soporten [*Buffer protocol*](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html).

Debes por tanto pasar una cadena de bytes con el contenido del fichero, no el fichero en si (`_io.BufferedReader`), por ejemplo usando el método `read`:

```
import hashlib



ruta = 'C:/Python/pep8es.pdf'

with open(ruta, mode='rb') as objeto_fichero:
    content = objeto_fichero.read()
    sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(content)
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(content)
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5(content)

print('sha1-> ', sha1_hash.hexdigest())
print('sha224->',sha256_hash.hexdigest())
print('md5->', md5_hash.hexdigest())
```

Dado que `read` carga el contenido del fichero al completo en memoria, si lo vas a aplicar sobre ficheros muy grandes y quieres evitar posibles problemas con la RAM, puedes leer el fichero en fragmentos del tamaño que desees y usar el método `update`:

```
import hashlib



BUFFSIZE = 131072  # Tamaño del fragmento en bytes
ruta = 'C:/Python/pep8es.pdf'

sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1()
sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
md5_hash = hashlib.md5()

with open(ruta, 'rb') as objeto_fichero:
    buff = objeto_fichero.read(BUFFSIZE)
    while buff:
        sha1_hash.update(buff)
        sha256_hash.update(buff)
        md5_hash.update(buff)
        buff = objeto_fichero.read(BUFFSIZE)

print('sha1-> ', sha1_hash.hexdigest())
print('sha224->',sha256_hash.hexdigest())
print('md5->', md5_hash.hexdigest())
```

Una cadena retornada por `input` en Python 3 tampoco es válida como argumento dado que son objetos `str` con codificación UTF-8 por defecto, para solucionarlo solo necesitas codificar la cadena para obtener un objeto `bytes`:

```
import hashlib


cadena_input = input('Introduce la cadena para sacar su hash: ')
cadena_cod = cadena_input.encode("UTF-8")
sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(cadena_cod)
print('sha1-> ', sha1_hash.hexdigest())
```

Recuerda que debes cerrar siempre un archivo cuando dejas de usarlo de forma explícita con `close()` o usando el administrador de contexto con [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), no solo por buena práctica, sino porque dejar esto al recolector de basura puede provocar comportamientos indeseados...

Comment: lo primero gracias por la respuesta, tratando ver el codigo me surje una cuestion llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo python y me he encontrado el uso de `with  junto while` , me podrias de que se encarga `with` o donde puedo ver informacion sobre ello? Asi como el uso buffer, no comprendo el uso que haces respecto  la documentacion oficial.

Comment: `with` no tiene relación directa con el ciclo `while`,  `with` se usa con objetos que soportan el protocolo de administrador de contexto y garantiza que una o varias sentencias serán ejecutadas automáticamente. En este caso concreto se encarga de cerrar de forma adecuada el fichero por nosotros. Mírate esta pregunta: [¿Para qué sirve y cómo funciona la palabra clave “with” en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/31428/15089) o la documentación oficial [The with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) para más información. Un saludo.