# Extraer string de un fichero de text

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero extraer una string que he delimitado con dos palabras, de un txt.

He usado el siguiente código:

```
import re
file = open(r"a.txt", 'r')
s = re.search('STX(.*)EOT',file)
print (s.group(1))
```

Pero no consigo que funcione si intento extraerlo de un txt, en cambio, desde una string declarada en una variable si.

a.txt:

```
STXextraemeestoEOT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código, `file` es un objeto de tipo `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, no su contenido.

El contenido del archivo completo lo puedes obtener con `file.read()`

```
import re
file = open(r"test.txt", 'r')
s = re.search('STX(.*)EOT',file.read())
print (s.group(1))
```

Claro que si el archivo es muy grande, esto no es recomendable. Lo que hay que hacer es procesar línea por línea. Lo más usado en estos casos en un `for linea in file`:

```
import re
file = open(r"test.txt", 'r')
for linea in file:
    s = re.search('STX(.*)EOT',linea)
    if s:
        print (s.group(1))
```

Comment: ¿no respondiste a algo muy similar hace nada? Recuerdo a alguien trabajando directamente con el objeto fichero en lugar de con su contenido

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Ahora que lo mencionas, parece que si. No recuerdo si fue un comentario o una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la función del lenguaje `open()` no devuelve un `str`, **devuelve un objeto generador**. La formula más común de leer con `open()` es la siguiente.

```
import re

with open(r"a.txt", 'r') as f:
    file = f.readline()

s = re.search('STX(.*)EOT',file)
print(s.group(1))
```

Esta formula con `with` nos permite crear un contexto en el que una vez se sale el archivo se cierra. Aplicando el método `.readline()` que pertenece a los objetos `open()` leemos la primera linea y devuelve un string que es lo que necesitas.

Para evitar copiar una buena respuesta te dejo el enlace del `with` [¿Para qué sirve y cómo funciona la palabra clave with en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31428/para-qu%c3%a9-sirve-y-c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-palabra-clave-with-en-python/31451#31451)

Comment: Solo examina la primera línea. Si el texto viene en la segunda línea, no lo encuentra y además, `s` queda en `None` y el `print` falla.

Comment: Pero vamos a ver @CandidMoe el OP a puesto un ejemplo de su texto y tiene una linea, no tiene varias lineas...  además lee bien la respuesta, ya que lo indico claramente: "aplicando el método `readline()` pertenece al objeto `open()` leemos la primera linea y devuelve un string". No te preocupes si tu respuesta es otra forma de solucionarlo, yo la he votado positiva.