# Modificar fichero json con librería ujson

Tags: python, json, micropython

Tengo un fichero con el siguiente aspecto,

```
{"a":66,"b":20}
```

Necesito trabajarlo con la librería `ujson` y no solo eso, si no que solo dispongo de tres métodos, `ujson.load()`, `ujson.loads()` y `ujson.dumps()`, [documentación](https://alepycom.gitbooks.io/pycom-documentation/content/chapter/firmwareapi/micropython/ujson.html).

Leer el fichero no hay problema,

```
import ujson

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)
f.close()
```

El problema es modificarlo, pues yo se hacerlo con `ujson.dump()` pero no con `dumps()`. ¿Como hago para pasarle los datos correctamente?

Mi código actual es:

```
import ujson

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)
f.close()

data['a'] = 22

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    ujson.dumps(data)
f.close()
```

Pero así me crea un fichero vacío. Entiendo que se tiene que poder, pero no averiguo como. Si alguien supiera como solucionarlo estaría agradecido.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación dice:

> Return obj represented as a JSON string.

Que significa que le pasamos un objeto `json` y nos devuelve un string. Por tanto después debes escribir dicho string en el fichero. Para ello puedes usar el método `.write()` que tiene la clase `TextIOWrapper` (es decir el objeto que creas con `open()`). El código quedaría así:

```
import ujson

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)

data["a"] = 32

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(ujson.dumps(data))
```

Como puedes ver he quitado los `f.close()` ya que el propio `with` **cierra el fichero** al finalizar su contexto (cuano quitas la identación). Y esta es la razón por la que se utiliza `with`, **para no tener que usar el método `.close()`.**

Para evitar copiar una respuesta ya existente, te adjunto esta públicación [¿Para qué sirve y cómo funciona la palabra clave “with” en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31428/para-qu%c3%a9-sirve-y-c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-palabra-clave-with-en-python/31451#31451) que explica magníficamente como funciona `with`.

### Bonus

De hecho, puedes hacerlo todo en un solo contexto:

```
import ujson

with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)
    data["a"] = 22 
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(ujson.dumps(data))
    f.truncate()
```

- `r+`: sirve para abrir un archivo en modo lectura y escritura.
- `f.seek(0)`: indicamos que el puntero se encontrará en la posición 0, es decir al inicio del `json`
- `f.truncate()`: Trunca el `json` donde se ha quedado el puntero, sirve por si al sobreescribir, lo sobreescrito tiene un tamaño menor, que lo que había ntes