# Trabajar con directorio en python Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Intento comprobar si **existe un archivo en una carpeta de mi PC**.

```
source = open(r"C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS")
destination = open(r"C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS2")

if "test" in source:
    print ("correcto")
else:
    print ("incorrecto")
```

Si hay algun archivo con el nombre test en la ruta **source**, quiero que me imprima correcto, de lo contrario, incorrecto.

Con mi còdigo obtengo el siguiente error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\mopar\\Documents\\TESTS'
```

He ejecutado el IDLE con permisos de administrador, pero sigue sin funcionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Si tan solo quieres comprobar que existe

Si no quieres leer nada y solo quieres comprobar si existe, puedes usar la librería de Python `os` y su función `exists()`. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
import os
os.path.exists(r"C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS")
```

**Salida:** `True`

### Si quieres ver el contenido

Seguimos con la librería `os` puesto que es la encargada de estos procesos en Python, en este caso la función `listdir`

```
import os
source = os.listdir("C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS")

if "test.png" in source:
    print("correcto")
else:
    print("incorrecto")
```

**Salida:** `correcto`

Si no quieres buscar el nombre completo, tienes que iterar sobre la lista y ver si el string del archivo contiene lo que tu buscas:

```
for string in source:
    if "test" in string:
        print("correcto")
        break
```

Esto se da porque `in` al buscar en la lista, busca si es **exacto el nombre del fichero** y al buscar en los strings busca **si lo contiene**

**Salida:** `correcto`

### Si quieres leer el fichero

El problema es que estás intentando abrir un archivo en modo lectura, pero le estás pasando una carpeta. Esta ruta:

```
C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS
```

Es la ruta a una carpeta (o a un archivo que no existe). Lo correcto es que pongas la terminación del archivo, por ejemplo si el archivo se llama `TESTS` y es un `.txt` sería así:

```
C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS.txt
```

Si `TEST` fuera una carpeta que tiene dentro un archivo que quieres leer sería así:

```
C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS\<nombre_archivo>.<extension_archivo>
```

### Extra

- La utilización que haces del `if` no es correcta, ya que `open()` te devuelve un objeto `_io.TextIOWrapper` no un `str`
- La forma convencional de leer un fichero es con el manejador de contexto `with` [¿Para qué sirve y cómo funciona la palabra clave “with” en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31428/para-qu%c3%a9-sirve-y-c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-palabra-clave-with-en-python/31451#31451). Esto hará que junto con los método de la clase `open` se habra el fichero, se lea su contenido y después se cierre el fichero, por ejemplo:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\mopar\Documents\TESTS.csv") as f:
    source = f.read()
```

Comment: TESTS es una carpeta correcto, pero no quiero leer un archivo en concreto, quiero ver el contenido de la carpeta, es esto posible?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, espero que sea lo que buscas :)

Comment: No, la ruta ya se que existe, lo que quiero, como indico en la pregunta, es saber si "test" coincide con algún archivo de dentro de la carpeta. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo lo que buscas, en tu pregunta pones "Intento comprobar si existe un archivo en una carpeta de mi PC. Si hay algun archivo con el nombre test en la ruta source, quiero que me imprima correcto, de lo contrario, incorrecto.". Por lo tanto si haces `os.listdir` vas a ver lo que  hay en dichar ruta, y ya solo necesitarías comprobar con `if ... in ...` si se encuentra el archivo que buscas ¿No?

Comment: Pues eso, intento comprobar si existe un archivo (test.*) en una carpeta (\\TESTS) de mi PC.

Comment: Vale, he editado la pregunta y he añadido el ```if ... in ... ``` confirmame si es lo que necesitas por favor

Comment: Perfecto, solo que añadí la **r** antes de la ruta, ya que no me permitía leer el contenido. Ahora no se a que se debe pero el output es "incorrecto" a pesar de que el archivo si existe (es un png), seguiré investigando. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) He editado la pregunta explicandote ese problema. Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)